# create azure IOT hub device using .Net

Tags: c#, azure-iot-hub

I want to create IOT hub for a client. I have created IOT Hub using rest API but not able to find the way to create device in it. I am using Rest API to create IOT hub. It gets created But when I am trying to create device, I got unauthorized exception. I am using [this api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/iothub/deviceapi/putdevice).

Comment: Your question is lacking enough information for anyone to be able to help you. Which [authentication mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/iothub/deviceapi/putdevice#authenticationmechanism) are you using? Are there any details on the exception as to why it's failing?

Comment: I am not giving any key for authentication. will it auto approve?

Comment: The docs you linked to say  for SymmetricKey authentication _"If [the keys] are not specified, the Iot Hub generates both keys for the device with a default key length of 32 bytes"_. But I think you will have to add the appropriate Json in the body to tell it that's what you want to do.

Comment: var description = new
            {
                deviceId = "testiot",
                eTag="MA==",
                status="enabled"



            }; I have added this json

Comment: You'll might need to add something like `authentication="symmetricKey"`

Comment: What API are you using? the link you provided is broken.

Answer (score 2):

Use `RegistryManager` from the SDK `Microsoft.Azure.Devices` and a connection string from the *Shared Access Policies* tab in the Azure Portal with `registry write`:

```
var registryManager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
var device = new Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Device(name);
var deviceWithKeys = await registryManager.AddDeviceAsync(device);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need use IoT Hub SAS token to create device like this:

```
PUT /devices/device2?api-version=2016-11-14 HTTP/1.1
Host: [IOT-HUB-NAME].azure-devices.net
Authorization: SharedAccessSignature sr=[IOT-HUB-NAME].azure-devices.net&sig=[SIG]&se=1557553675&skn=iothubowner
Content-Type: application/json

{deviceId:"device2"}
```

You can get IoT Hub SAS token from [device explorer](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/tree/master/tools/DeviceExplorer#configure-an-iot-hub-connection).

Comment: Anyone have an actually working C# code snippet, with all the components which works using a SAS token generated by device explorer?

Comment: Here is an example:https://github.com/Microsoft/iot-samples/blob/master/DeviceManagement/csharp/CreateDeviceIdentity/Program.cs